# Using asyncio.Queue for producer-consumer flow

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm confused about how to use `asyncio.Queue` for a particular producer-consumer pattern in which both the producer and consumer operate concurrently and independently.

First, consider this example, which closely follows that from the [docs for `asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#examples):

```
import asyncio
import random
import time

async def worker(name, queue):
    while True:
        sleep_for = await queue.get()
        await asyncio.sleep(sleep_for)
        queue.task_done()
        print(f'{name} has slept for {sleep_for:0.2f} seconds')

async def main(n):
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    total_sleep_time = 0
    for _ in range(20):
        sleep_for = random.uniform(0.05, 1.0)
        total_sleep_time += sleep_for
        queue.put_nowait(sleep_for)
    tasks = []
    for i in range(n):
        task = asyncio.create_task(worker(f'worker-{i}', queue))
        tasks.append(task)
    started_at = time.monotonic()
    await queue.join()
    total_slept_for = time.monotonic() - started_at
    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()
    # Wait until all worker tasks are cancelled.
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    print('====')
    print(f'3 workers slept in parallel for {total_slept_for:.2f} seconds')
    print(f'total expected sleep time: {total_sleep_time:.2f} seconds')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    n = 3 if len(sys.argv) == 1 else sys.argv[1]
    asyncio.run(main())
```

There is one finer detail about this script: the items are put into the queue synchronously, with `queue.put_nowait(sleep_for)` over a conventional for-loop.

My goal is to create a script that uses `async def worker()` (or `consumer()`) and `async def producer()`.  Both should be scheduled to run concurrently.  No one consumer coroutine is explicitly tied to or chained from a producer.

How can I modify the program above so that the producer(s) is its own coroutine that can be scheduled concurrently with the consumers/workers?

---

<sub>There is a second example from [PYMOTW](https://pymotw.com/3/asyncio/synchronization.html#queues).  It requires the producer to know the number of consumers ahead of time, and uses `None` as a signal to the consumer that production is done.</sub>

Answer (score 134, accepted):

> How can I modify the program above so that the producer(s) is its own coroutine that can be scheduled concurrently with the consumers/workers?

The example can be generalized without changing its essential logic:

- Move the insertion loop to a separate producer coroutine.
- Start the consumers in the background, letting them process the items as they are produced.
- With the consumers running, start the producers and wait for them to finish producing items, as with `await producer()` or `await gather(*producers)`, etc.
- Once all producers are done, wait for consumers to process the remaining items with `await queue.join()`.
- Cancel the consumers, all of which are now idly waiting for the queue to deliver the next item, which will never arrive as we know the producers are done.

Here is an example implementing the above:

```
import asyncio, random
 
async def rnd_sleep(t):
    # sleep for T seconds on average
    await asyncio.sleep(t * random.random() * 2)
 
async def producer(queue):
    while True:
        # produce a token and send it to a consumer
        token = random.random()
        print(f'produced {token}')
        if token < .05:
            break
        await queue.put(token)
        await rnd_sleep(.1)
 
async def consumer(queue):
    while True:
        token = await queue.get()
        # process the token received from a producer
        await rnd_sleep(.3)
        queue.task_done()
        print(f'consumed {token}')
 
async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
 
    # fire up the both producers and consumers
    producers = [asyncio.create_task(producer(queue))
                 for _ in range(3)]
    consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))
                 for _ in range(10)]
 
    # with both producers and consumers running, wait for
    # the producers to finish
    await asyncio.gather(*producers)
    print('---- done producing')
 
    # wait for the remaining tasks to be processed
    await queue.join()
 
    # cancel the consumers, which are now idle
    for c in consumers:
        c.cancel()
 
asyncio.run(main())
```

Note that in real-life producers and consumers, especially those that involve network access, you probably want to catch IO-related exceptions that occur during processing. If the exception is recoverable, as most network-related exceptions are, you can simply catch the exception and log the error. You should still invoke `task_done()` because otherwise `queue.join()` will hang due to an unprocessed item. If it makes sense to re-try processing the item, you can return it into the queue prior to calling `task_done()`. For example:

```
# like the above, but handling exceptions during processing:
async def consumer(queue):
    while True:
        token = await queue.get()
        try:
            # this uses aiohttp or whatever
            await process(token)
        except aiohttp.ClientError as e:
            print(f"Error processing token {token}: {e}")
            # If it makes sense, return the token to the queue to be
            # processed again. (You can use a counter to avoid
            # processing a faulty token infinitely.)
            #await queue.put(token)
        queue.task_done()
        print(f'consumed {token}')
```

Comment: I'm writing about asyncio with `aiohttp` & [`aiofiles`](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles) and want to mention queues in a section---do you mind if I link to & cite this answer?

Comment: @BradSolomon Sure, go ahead!

Comment: I'm trying to adapt this to test if files exist in a directory, but it doesn't seem to interleave producers and consumers asynchronously.  All producers are first generated, followed by consumers.  How do I modify this to work on cpu-bound processes like `if pathlib.Path().exists(): ...`.

Comment: @pylang If your code is CPU-bound (or blocking in some other way not handled by asyncio), asyncio will not interleave it automatically. In that case, use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to off-load the blocking code to a thread pool. Then you'd write `if await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: pathlib.Path(...).exists()): ...`

Comment: I think that will be the right approach according to this blog https://giuseppeciotta.net/threadpoolexecutor-and-processpoolexecutor-modern-python-idioms.html.  Many thanks.

Comment: How would I keep the producers running forever, if they get an endless stream of elements to add to the queue?

Comment: @JohannesPertl The program should work unchanged with the producers running forever, as both the producers and the consumers run in the background. Such variant will simply never reach the "done producing" line and will consequently never proceed to cancel the consumers.

Comment: So, if there is a problem with the worker after it `queue.get()`s and thus never `queue.task_done()`... what happens? How can another worker `queue.get()` the item and finish processing? How can you turn off this so you just have to `get()` and don't have to `task_done()`? I want to use the double-entry/accountant pattern to check all the items on the queue are done https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/gammap/fault_tollerant_data_processing_pods/

Comment: @CpILL A missing `task_done()` would cause `queue.join()` to hang forever. A non-toy worker will probably catch exceptions and/or call `task_done` in a finally block. Assuming the exception is recoverable, the worker can even re-enqueue it before calling `task_done`, ensuring that it's picked up by a worker again. The cited pattern with two queues seems unnecessary, and using `task_done` makes nice use of the somewhat unusual "join" capability of Python queues.

Comment: @user4815162342 That is true, but i guess it assumes that the problems are known ahead of time and we also know how to deal with them. I was thinking "fail fast" and just stick the job back on the end of the queue and keep going.

Comment: @CpILL Sure, you can do that (that's what "assuming the exception is recoverable" refers to), just remember to also call `task_done` anyway, so that the current dequeue is counted as resolved. The queue won't mind that you've readded the same object, it just counts the number of enqueues and dequeues.

Comment: @user4815162342 Hi, I tried to print id(self) in consumer while it always prints the same value while if I print id of consumers in a for loop in main() it gives me different ids. May I ask why is this? Thanks.

Comment: @stephen It's hard to tell what your program is printing, as the code in this answer (as well as code in the question) doesn't even use `self`. Whatever it is, you should probably ask a separate question, and show the exact code that you are running (reduced to a minimal size that still reproduces the effect you're asking about).

Comment: An error in this example:  if you want the `producer()` and `consumer()` output to align, the conditional `break` in `producer()` must be moved after the `await queue.put(token)`