# What's the point of task_done of asyncio queue?

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio

I'm using asyncio.Queue to store data. According to the docs, after each `queue.get()` I should call `queue.task_done()`. Why?

Comment: "after each queue.get() I should call queue.task_done()" - when using that mechanism, you should call `task_done` *after the task is done*. This is technically after `queue.get()`, but not immediately after.

Comment: You only need to call `task_done()` if you plan on calling `await queue.join()` to await the event when everything that was put in the queue has been processed. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52615705/1600898) for an example.