# Python CancelledError with asyncio queue

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio, producer-consumer

I use code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582685/using-asyncio-queue-for-producer-consumer-flow) answer, but get `asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError` when queue is empty. In real project, I add tasks to queue from consumers, that's why I use `while True` statement

I compress that code to make debug more easily:

```
import asyncio
import traceback


async def consumer(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    try:
        while True:
            number = await queue.get()  # here is exception
            queue.task_done()
            print(f'consumed {number}')
    except BaseException:
        traceback.print_exc()


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    for i in range(3):
        await queue.put(i)
    consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue)) for _ in range(1)]
    await queue.join()
    for c in consumers:
        c.cancel()


asyncio.run(main())
```

And error:

```
consumed 0
consumed 1
consumed 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abionics/Downloads/BaseAsyncScraper/ttt.py", line 8, in consumer
    number = await queue.get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/queues.py", line 166, in get
    await getter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

By the way, the documentation of `queue.get()` says that `If queue is empty, wait until an item is available`. What is the real reason of this error? Maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because you cancel the task:

[Task.cancel](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel):

> Request the Task to be cancelled.
>
> This arranges for a CancelledError exception to be thrown into the
> wrapped coroutine on the next cycle of the event loop.

You have a few options to handle this:

**1. Use [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)**

> If return_exceptions is True, exceptions are treated the same as
> successful results, and aggregated in the result list.

```
await queue.join()

for c in consumers:
    c.cancel()

await asyncio.gather(*consumers, return_exceptions=True)
```

**2. Catch the exception in the consumer**

```
async def consumer(q):
    while True:
        num = await q.get()

        try:                
            print(f"Working on: {num}")
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print(f"Exiting...")
            break
        finally:
            q.task_done()
```

**3. Suppress the exception**

```
from contextlib import suppress

async def consumer(q):
    with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        while True:
            num = await q.get()
            print(f"Working on: {num}")
            q.task_done()
```

Comment: which one of the above do you suggest? im leaning towards 1. but 2. looks clean as well